# Select limit result in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have table with these data:

```
Id  City        Amount
1   London      25000
2   New York    20000
3   London      23000
4   Paris       22000
5   Moscow      18000
6   London      21000
7   New York    19000
8   Moscow      26000
9   London      24000
10  Moscow      16000
11  London      15000
12  Moscow      23000
13  Paris       19000
14  New York    15000
15  London      26000
```

I must create SQL as what to get the results as this?

```
Id  City        Amount
1   London      25000
2   New York        20000
3   London      23000
4   Paris       22000
5   Moscow      18000
7   New York        19000
8   Moscow      26000
13  Paris       19000
```

That means I just want to get the maximum of one city only to appear 2 times.

I just want to get the first two records or the last two records

Thanks!

Comment: 'first two records or the last two records' - or any random 2?

Comment: No random, only first 2 or last 2 are accepted.

Comment: If your mysql version is not 8.0 or above then you can use row number simulation. If you google mysql row number you will find lots of examples.

Comment: @MrNinh what is your Mysql version ?

Answer (score -2):

If your **MySQL version < 8.0**, you can simulate `RowNumber` functionality, using [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). To achieve `Partition By` functionality based on grouping, we will use two session variables, one for the row number and the other for storing the old `City` to compare it with the current one, and increment it by 1, if belonging to same `City` group, else reset to 1.

Following code will get your **first two records**. You can easily change it to get first n records, by changing 2 to n in the query.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @city_var = '';
SELECT inner_nest.Id, 
       inner_nest.City, 
       inner_nest.Amount 
FROM (
      SELECT 
            @row_number:=CASE 
                             WHEN @city_var = City THEN @row_number + 1
                             ELSE 1
                         END AS num, 
            Id, 
            @city_var:=City as City, 
            Amount
      FROM
          table_name
      ORDER BY 
              City) AS inner_nest 
WHERE inner_nest.num <= 2 
ORDER BY inner_nest.Id ASC
```

**

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e96f9/1)

**

Comment: I don't care Amount, I just want to get the first 2 records or last 2 records

Comment: @MrNinh I have edited my code completely. Check the solution. It should work for you definitely, if you are using Mysql version < 8.0

Comment: How to i get 2 last record?

Comment: @MrNinh please consider marking this as accepted answer (green tick). Thanks. I will edit the answer afterwards and add your requirements for last 2 record